# FancyBox opens image on its own page

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've tried several of the other answers posted to this question and I still cant figure it out.

[Here is the site that has the problem](http://ryansamul.com/dark/gallery-subject-new.html).

I admit do not have real programing experience except for HTML and what I've deciphered for myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to be more clear with your question and add details. Post the code that has problems. Post what you have tried and did not work. Just viewing the problem can't help others that much to answer. What is the behaviour you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [custom.js](http://ryansamul.com/dark/js/custom.js) file, your are using `jQuery.noConflict()` to initialize your functions :

```
jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
 //.... 
});
```

...so far so good, however inside your main page your fancybox initialization is not using `jQuery.noConflict()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox();
 });
</script>
```

... so modifying it like this should do the trick :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: holy $hit!  thank you so much!  what do i click for you to get a higher rating or whatever?

Comment: also, do you know if there is a way to paginate the thumbnails that appear under the opened image?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you haven't actually included fancybox properly.

I have the following 404 errors when visiting your site:

```
'http://ryansamul.com/dark/fancy/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.3'
'http://ryansamul.com/dark/fancy/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.6'
'http://ryansamul.com/dark/fresco/css/fresco/fresco.css'
'http://ryansamul.com/dark/fancy/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.0'
'http://ryansamul.com/dark/js/swfsubject/swfsubject.js'
'http://ryansamul.com/dark/fresco/js/fresco/fresco.js'
```

Maybe you forgot to upload these files to your server? Or have the paths wrong.

Comment: You need to open your JavaScript console and check for errors. Looks like you've got a conflicted variable: `$`.

Answer (score 0):

The photos that open in a new tab have a `class="portfolio-item-preview"` instead of the `class="fancybox-thumb"`. Changing this will make the fancybox initialize properly on all elements.